# How to get current GPS location from Pixhawk?

Tags: gps, location, px4

I'm trying to write a program for the pixhawk that compares the drone's current location (GPS coordinates) to already pre-established locations in my program.
When the current location of the drone matches one of the pre-established location I want to launch a script on my computer... I have searched various forums trying to find if there is a way to obtain the GPS location directly from the pixhawk. I want to do this without Qgroundcontrol... Any pointers?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Its been over 5 years but i dont think i did, atleast i dont remember. MAVLINK’s message protocols contains the coordinates but i don’t think i was ever successful intercepting the message of interest and extracting the coordinates directly from the PX4 the way i wanted to. As development for drones has advanced there’s programmable interfaces like dronekit or MAVSDK that allow you to do it now though, could check those out.